# Proportional editing doesn't work

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, proportional-editing

I enabled the ***Proportional Editing*** option and tried to scale the part of the mesh. Although I can see the proportional editing ring it does not work. What may cause this problem?
[image]

Comment: your pivot point is set to Individual Origin, you need to change it to Median Point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make Proportional Editing work on the mesh you need to change pivot point from Individual Origin to Median Point.

[image]