# Can't change mouse influence in proportional editing mode

Tags: interface, edit-mode, sculpting

I press O and I see it change to Proportional Editing mode, but when I press G and mouse wheel down/up, or arrow keys down/up, it doesn't change the influence area.

["You must press PgUpPgDown or use the scroll wheel *during* a transform action such as Translate (G), Rotate (R), or Scale (S)."](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/change-radius-for-proportional-editing)

And I am, I press G and then I tried to scroll to change influence, but it's not working.

[To make Proportional Editing work on the mesh you need to change pivot point from Individual Origin to Median Point.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27505/proportional-editing-doesnt-work)

Done this aswell and it's not working

Comment: Test with another mouse. I have had this issue previously and fixed it with a new mouse.

Comment: Can't get a new mouse right now ._. but ty /// but then arrow keys should work

Comment: Does the number in the header (Proportional size) remain the same when you use the wheel or the arrow keys? Can you zoom using the mouse wheel?

Comment: ohhh ok ahaha I was moving the mouse wheel just now and nothing was happening, but I looked at the header and the number was changing, so I kept wheeling and eventually the circle was visible lols haha tyy

Comment: Just hold <kbd> G</kbd> and increase the influence values. Also make sure that pivot point is set to the individual origin. The Youtube tutorial mentioned below might help the users facing the said issue.
[Proportional editing issue fixed - Click on the link to check the tutorial](https://youtu.be/lONMIOL2fPk)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm adding an answer here because effected users might overlook what is written in the comments:

If you're working with large scale models to scale (say at a distance 100Km), the influence radius will likely be too small for you to notice, even if you scroll multiple times. When you grab  <kbd>G</kbd> a vertex or edge, press the page up key and keep it pressed until the scope starts to become visible. *Proportional Size* at the bottom of your 3D view might appear to not change, but it eventually will.

Hope this spares another soul some misery.

Comment: I had similar but opposite problem, my soi was huge, so I had to continuously scroll (up?!) to reduce it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the simple answer is that if you are turning the mouse wheel and you see the proportional size number is changing (it is next to the Dx, Dy, Dz numbers), then everything is working just fine. All you have to do is keep scrolling in the direction that makes the "proportional size" number get smaller and you will eventually see the sphere of influence.

Answer (score 3):

Try to hold <kbd>G</kbd> then mouse wheel up/down

Answer (score 0):

Having pressed <kbd>G</kbd> in the proportional edit mode don't press the wheel, just scroll it. Pressing the wheel you change your mouse's operation mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I have enabled the *Mirror* modifier. Unfortunately am enabling *Proportional Editing* and increase the radius with mouse wheel at mirror side not at the original side, so that I can't view the resizer.

It should be done in original side.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above advice that the proportion size only shows while using the feature, if the number is maxed out at 1000, scrolling the mouse wheel down will give the false impression nothing is happening. Scrolling UP will reduce the number. >_<

Answer (score 0):

[image: enter size here once action is performed]

1. Select proportional editing
2. Select your object or vertices etc
3. Perform scale - rotate etc then (in the **dialogue options box** that appears just after your transform -before you click away! - select dropdown arrow to open and **change the value** for size of sphere of influence)
4. Next time you perform the operation it will have a new value (greater or lesser influence)
   As others have mentioned - do pay attention to the size of your object and distance in relation to influence area.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above advice that the proportion size only shows while using the feature, if the number is maxed out at 1000, scrolling the mouse wheel down will give the false impression nothing is happening.

Scrolling up will reduce the number. Look to the top to see the numbers changing