# Donut Tutorial in Version 2.79

Tags: modeling

I loaded v2.79 because I can't load the latest version because of my old Mac operating system, El capitan, and my old machine won't load upgrades beyond that, so in the famous donut tutorial he uses proportional editing to distort the torus. My controls do not work the same at all. At 7:30 in part 2 of the Blender Beginner Tutorial Blender Guru says scroll up or down with the scroll wheel/button and when I do it does not do what it does in his version.

Comment: Hello, what is your question ? You feel like the proportional editing doesn't behave the same ? Be careful with it, if you have the radius set too high, you won't see a circle on your screen, you have to scroll your mouse until you see it. You can see the radius in the top of the screen or the bottom iirc see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/cant-change-mouse-influence-in-proportional-editing-mode/112355

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, that works!